# Django Rest Framework - OPTIONS request - Get foreign key choices

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Lets say I have two models in Django, and I'm using standard Viewsets and Serializers to expose endpoints.

ModelA has a ForeignKey field to ModelB. When I do an OPTIONS request to the ModelA endpoint it just lists it as a field, like below:

```
"actions": {
    "POST": {
        "pk": {
            "type": "integer",
            "required": false,
            "read_only": true,
            "label": "ID"
        },
        "created": {
            "type": "datetime",
            "required": false,
            "read_only": true,
            "label": "Created"
        },

        "foreign_key_field": {
            "type": "field",
            "required": true,
            "read_only": false,
            "label": "Wcp"
        },
    }
}
```

I would like it to have a 'choices' property which pulls down every single instance of Model B. This way in my Angular frontend I can create a dropdown of all the choice.

I think I need to make a new MetaData class or somthing. But I can't find any solid way of doing this. I also think this functionality has changed in 3.X of DRF so old answers around the internet no longer help.

Cheers,
Dean

Answer (score 5):

Made some improvements to @ralfzen his answer to improve serialization.
Also needed to use RelatedField instead of just ManyRelatedField

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.metadata import SimpleMetadata
from rest_framework.relations import ManyRelatedField, RelatedField


class MyMetaData(SimpleMetadata):

    def get_field_info(self, field):
        field_info = super(MyMetaData, self).get_field_info(field)
        if isinstance(field, (RelatedField, ManyRelatedField)):
            field_info['choices'] = [
                {
                    'value': choice_value,
                    'display_name': force_text(choice_name, strings_only=True)
                }
                for choice_value, choice_name in field.get_choices().items()
            ]
        return field_info


class MyView(APIView):
    metadata_class = MyMetaData
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this Issue solved thanks @detoix hint like this:

```
from rest_framework.relations import ManyRelatedField
from rest_framework.metadata import SimpleMetadata


class MyMetaData(SimpleMetadata):

    def get_field_info(self, field):
        field_info = super(MyMetaData, self).get_field_info(field)
        if isinstance(field, ManyRelatedField):
            field_info['choices'] = field.get_choices()
        return field_info
```

And in views.py:

```
class ViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    metadata_class = MyMetadata
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a perfect answer as well, but my way of achieving this was mapping json items to their ids and storing such a collection like this (in angular):

```
$scope.nodes = response.data; //original data retrieved from django
$scope.nodesIds = response.data.map(function (v) { return v.id; }); //particular ids
```

doing this, you're able to use that map in ng-options in such a  way:

```
<select ng-model="node_start" ng-options="node for node in nodesIds" />
```

Any better ideas?

//After thorough consideration (it turns out that this is a 'manual' approach)

```
from rest_framework.metadata import SimpleMetadata
class MyMetadata(SimpleMetadata):
    def get_serializer_info(self, serializer):
        orderedDict = super().get_serializer_info(serializer)
        orderedDict['foreign_key_field']['choices'] = [x.id for x in Node.objects.all()]
        return orderedDict

class ViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    metadata_class = MyMetadata
```

Please let me know if it works for you :)

//Finally (smart approach with changes in default DRF code)

If you want it fully automatically, all you have to do is adding three lines of code to metadata.py:

on top:

```
from rest_framework.relations import PrimaryKeyRelatedField
```

in get_field_info method:

```
if type(field) is PrimaryKeyRelatedField:
    field_info['choices'] = [x.id for x in field.queryset.all()]
```

Comment: Well I was planning on solving things on the Django side of things. I know I need to make some change to DRF - probably the metadata class which handles Options requests

Comment: Doesn't simple ng-options="node.id as node.id for node in nodes" meet your needs? Maybe something is not clear to me but I don't understand why not to store forein keys by their id?

Comment: I'm using Angular 4, plus that has nothing to do with how DRF handles Options.

Comment: Ok. What comes to my mind is to create your own class deriving from default SimpleMetadata - in this class you need to override determine_metadata method and add choices property there. Works for me. Should I post snippet in another answer?

Comment: Yes please. That would be great! 